# Moving existing Tomcat installation with running Java EE App to a new server

Tags: jakarta-ee, tomcat

I am a starter and I couldn't realize how to create a tomcat web server from scratch. I have searched many forms and found different results. Actually I am working on an existing tomcat web server which serves our Java EE web application; however, I have to move it to a new remote computer where it should work like the current one. What steps should I follow to accomplish this task?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In order to install a new tomcat server, you need to download the tomcat package from their website and unpack it. Additionally you have to set the CATALINA_HOME variable to the folder. If you have any changes in the configuration you need to repeat them on the new server. Then you can just deploy your application like on your local server.

Comment: Thank you in advance for the reply. I'm trying to configure it.

Comment: In mycurrent working environment, I'm extracting the web-app to .war file in my local computer and put it to webapps directory of the tomcat server in remote computer and tomcat deploys it. Do I have to specify the .war file name somewhere in tomcat server or will it deploy by putting .war file into webapps directory in tomcat server.

Comment: Usually auto-deploy is activated. That means tomcat automatically discovers the .war and deploys it.